# usage of data.table within a function

Tags: r, data.table

I find R package data.table very useful when using on an interactive console.
However when using it inside a function it makes things much more tricky

```
library(data.table)
flights <- fread("https://github.com/arunsrinivasan/flights/wiki/NYCflights14/flights14.csv")

flights[origin == "JFK" & month == 6L,
        .(m_arr = mean(arr_delay), m_dep = mean(dep_delay))]
```

But this fails:

```
x="arr_delay" # x and y are passed from arguments of a function
y="dep_delay"
flights[origin == "JFK" & month == 6L,
        .(m_arr = mean(x), m_dep = mean(y))]
```

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 3):

The option would be to specify it in `.SDcols` and then get the `mean` from `SD`

```
setnames(flights[origin == "JFK" & month == 6L,
    lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = c(x, y)], c('m_arr', 'm_dep'))[]
#     m_arr    m_dep
#1: 5.839349 9.807884
```

and it can be wrapped in a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, col1, col2) {

  setnames(dat[origin == "JFK" & month == 6L,
       lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = c(col1, col2)],  c('m_arr', 'm_dep'))[]
 }

f1(flights, x, y)
```

---

If we don't want to do that way, then `get` is an option to get the values

```
flights[origin == "JFK" & month == 6L,
    .(m_arr = mean(get(x)), m_dep = mean(get(y)))]
#     m_arr    m_dep
#1: 5.839349 9.807884
```

Or another option is `eval(as.name`

```
f2 <- function(dat, col1, col2) {

  dat[origin == "JFK" & month == 6L,
    .(m_arr = mean(eval(as.name(col1))), m_dep = mean(eval(as.name(col2))))]

}
f2(flights, x, y)
#     m_arr    m_dep
#1: 5.839349 9.807884
```

---

An option using `tidyverse` would be

```
f3 <- function(dat, col1, col2) {

  dat %>% 
       filter(origin == "JFK",  month == 6L) %>%
       summarise_at(vars(col1, col2), mean) %>%
       rename(m_arr := !! rlang::sym(col1),
              m_dep := !! rlang::sym(col2))

  }

f3(flights, x, y)
#     m_arr    m_dep
#1 5.839349 9.807884
```

Comment: nice one on `get`. Will this *always* works? Just worried about the exact environment in which it will be evaluated. Also columns names as not kept: compare `flights[, .(sum((arr_delay + dep_delay) < 0), arr_delay, dep_delay)]` with `x="arr_delay"; y="dep_delay"; flights[, .(sum((get(x) + get(y)) < 0), get(x), get(y))]`

Comment: @RockScience  If it is highly nested env, you may have to specify the `envir` argument of `get`

Comment: @RockScience You can always use `setnames`  Just saw your updated comment with code. i.e. `setnames(flights[, .(sum((get(x) + get(y)) < 0), get(x), get(y))], 2:3, c(x, y))[]`